# If I have length of the curve and its projection along X axis then how can I find the angle made by uppermost end point with the horizontal?

Tags: calculus

The question is something like[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv2UU.jpg), I have given the curve length as 4 units and its projection along a vertical axis that is y-axis as 2 units and also the angle of the lowermost end point of the curve with horizontal is zero and I have to find the angle made by tangent at the uppermost end point of the curve with the horizontal, actually it is a physics question of newtons laws of motion I have done it by considering tension in the string and using its uniform mass density but I think It can be done by calculus also easily.
My attempt by using physics Newton's law of motion:- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbM4m.jpg)

Comment: Please show us your attempts and thoughts behind the task so that we can really help you and not just solve the task.

Comment: Do you have the equation of said curve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not solvable in the general case.

We have a curve $C$, which we will parametrize as a path $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$, such that $\gamma(t) = (x(t),y(t))$ and we know that

$$\ell =\int_C{\mathrm{d}s}=\int_0^1{\sqrt{\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t} = 4$$

And that

$$\Delta y = \int_0^1{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}y} = y(1) - y(0) = 2$$

From this we are trying to find a value for

$$\Delta x =\int_0^1{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}t}$$

It is not possible to isolate only one value for $\Delta x$, as multiple curves (even with the more stringent conditions of monotonically increasing $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, and $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=0$ at $t=0$) exist which satisfy our first and second equations. Consider your catenary-like curve from the question and an exponential curve, or logarithmic curve, or sinusoid for example (adjusted to have zero derivative at the origin).

If you did have an explicit parametrization $\gamma$ for $C$, though, this could be solved with calculus.

Comment: Now I have corrected the question, please try it now